# Why is Visual Studio Code not showing mypy errors when I have my package installed in editable mode in a venv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mypy, vscode-python

I have a Python project which uses `mypy` for type checking. The root of my project contains a `setup.py` and the package folder `rise`, along with a virtual environment folder `venv`. Both my shells and VSCode are set to use this virtual environment.

Most of the time, this setup works great: VSCode runs `mypy` every time I save and marks the errors with squiggles and in the Problems window. But for some reason, if I install the `rise` package in editable mode using `pip install -e .`, type checking in VSCode **never finds any type errors.** This does *not* happen if I install it in non-editable mode with `pip install .`, and if I uninstall the editable-mode package and reload the VSCode window, it immediately starts working normally again.

---

If I go into the Python output in the Output window, I see:

```
> ./venv/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.18.2/pythonFiles/linter.py -m mypy --show-column-numbers --strict ./rise/action.py

[...output from pylint, which is also configured and is working normally, clipped]

##########Linting Output - mypy##########

Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Yet if I copy and paste the command it's echoing into the terminal, there is in fact an error:

```
$ ./venv/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.18.2/pythonFiles/linter.py -m mypy --show-column-numbers --strict ./rise/action.py
rise/action.py:140:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "None", expected "bool")  [return-value]
```

I'm stumped as to how to troubleshoot this further, and I haven't been able to find any reference to this issue anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up installing the `Mypy` [extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matangover.mypy) and removing mypy from my linters configuration. The extension doesn't suffer from this bug (or misconfiguration, or whatever it is), and it runs faster to boot.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue. Perhaps an explicit setting of severity in the settings.json file should help:

```
"python.linting.mypyCategorySeverity.error":"Warning"
```

Comment: I came here wondering how to make the mypy errors more visually noticeable. This was exactly what I wanted, though I set mine to "Error" personally.